# Multiple Parameter condition using Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have the following in my selection expert:

```
(
if {?Job} <> "All" then
 {SPSYSPRO_PO_CapexJobs;1.MJob} = {?Job}
else
  true
) OR
(
if  {?Supplier} <> "All" then
  {SPSYSPRO_PO_CapexJobs;1.MJob}= {?Job}
else
  true
)
```

However its not doing what I want ^^ 
What I require is if Job has not value selected then use the supplier's list to obtain data.
So if Job has no value and Supplier = multiple values it should bring me all those suppliers jobs, or vice versa...
If I select Job = All and choose multiple supplier's it should bring me back all jobs for just those suppliers selected and vice versa...

Hey just thought ill add my SP here, then you might understand what im looking for as your formula don't work in this regard.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(PD.PurchaseOrder,9,7) PurchaseOrder
          ,PD.[Line]
          ,PD.[MStockCode]
          ,PD.[MStockDes]
          ,PD.[MOrderQty]
          ,PD.[MReceivedQty]
          ,SUBSTRING(RD.Supplier,9,7) Supplier
          ,AP.SupplierName  
          ,PH.OrderEntryDate CreateDate
          ,PH.OrderStatus
          ,PD.[MLatestDueDate]
          ,PD.[MLastReceiptDat]
          ,PD.[MDiscValue]
          ,PD.[MPrice]
          ,PD.[MForeignPrice]
          ,PD.MJob 
          ,PD.[MRequisition]
          ,PD.[MRequisitionLine]

      FROM [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[PorMasterDetail] PD
      INNER JOIN [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[PorMasterHdr] PH
       on PD.PurchaseOrder = PH.PurchaseOrder
        INNER JOIN [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].ReqDetail RD
        on PD.MRequisition = RD.Requisition and PD.MRequisitionLine = RD.Line 
        INNER JOIN [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].ApSupplier AP
        on RD.Supplier = AP.Supplier  
      Where SUBSTRING(PD.MJob,1,1)= 'C'
      and PD.MCompleteFlag <> 'Y'
      and PH.OrderStatus <> '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need only jobs for the suppliers that are selected then it would be better you use the sub report

In main report create a parameter for suppliers and jobs and pass suppliers parameter to sub report and link job parameter in main report to sub report
using sub report links and write the below formula in sub report `record selection formula`

For parameters create 2 default values `All`, `None` and your normal list

```
if {?Job} = "All" and ({?suppliers} <> "ALL" and {?suppliers} <> "none") then
 {SPSYSPRO_PO_CapexJobs;1.MJob} = {?Job} and
 {SPSYSPRO_PO_CapexJobs;1.Msuppliers} in ("list of comma saperated suppliers")
//For above case you need to have relation between jobs and suppliers
else if 
(({?Job} = "All" or {?suppliers} = "none") and {?suppliers} <> "ALL")
then {SPSYSPRO_PO_CapexJobs;1.MJob} = {?Job}
else if 
({?Job} <> "All" and ({?suppliers} = "ALL" or {?Job} = "none"))
then {SPSYSPRO_PO_CapexJobs;1.MJob}= {?Job}
```

if you don't want to use the sub report then retrieve all records and do the selection in crystal reports

```
if 
    (({?Job} = "All" or {?suppliers} = "none") and {?suppliers} <> "ALL")
    then {SPSYSPRO_PO_CapexJobs;1.MJob} = {SPSYSPRO_PO_CapexJobs;1.MJob}        else if 
    ({?Job} <> "All" and ({?suppliers} = "ALL" or {?Job} = "none"))
    then {SPSYSPRO_PO_CapexJobs;1.MJob}= {SPSYSPRO_PO_CapexJobs;1.Supplier}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Siva, I have tried your query without sub-report as my query or sp looks as follow and don't think I require a subreport. I added my sp code so perhaps you will have a better understanding what im after.

Comment: Hi Siva, the query still don't work if I select for e.g. None for Job and just one specific Supplier it returns nothing even if there is jobs for that supplier. If you select All and one supplier it returns all the data, not just data for that supplier. So I need to say e.g. Job = All and Supplier = A then I want to return all jobs for that supplier, or for multiple supplier. Then if I select for Job = A, B, C and select supplier = All then I want to display all the jobs for that regardless of who the supplier is.

Comment: See if this is the requirement...then use sub report else retrive all and show what is requried and supress remaining